# A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF 6 Code First model with attribute `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` that is NOT the primary key, and I'm getting the "null store-generated value" when an insert is attempted.  Why is this happening?  The full exception is:

> A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member
>   'RandomColumnWithAnIdentity' of type
>   'MyCompany.MyDataLayer.Entities.TheChildTable'.

So it's erroring on the column that is NOT the primary key, but is marked with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity.  Is this supported with EF?

The entity (this is a child in a foreign key relationship):

```
[Table("TheChildTable")]
public class TheChildTable : TheBaseType
{
    public Guid TheChildTableId { get; set; }

    public Guid TheParentTableId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RandomColumnWithAnIdentity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Param { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual TheParentTable TheParentTable { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping for the parent (the child has no mapping):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TheParentTable>()
            .HasMany(e => e.TheChildTables)
            .WithRequired(e => e.TheParentTable)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**Update 1:** Here is the additional code for the parent type and base type.

Here's **TheParentTable**.  Interestingly, it also has an Identity column, but this one is working:

```
[Table("TheParentTable")]
public class TheParentTable : TheBaseType
{
    public TheParentTable()
    {
        this.TheChildTables = new HashSet<TheChildTable>();
    }

    public Guid TheParentTableId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RandomColumnWithAnIdentity { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TheChildTable> TheChildTables { get; set; }
}
```

Here's **TheBaseType**:

```
public abstract class TheBaseType : IAuditable
{
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

    public Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

    public Guid? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an excerpt from the DbContext implementation:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
        public virtual DbSet<TheParentTable> TheParentTables { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<TheChildTable> TheChildTables { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#if DEBUG
            this.Database.Log = s => Debug.Write(s);
#endif

            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

modelBuilder.Entity<TheParentTable>()
            .HasMany(e => e.TheChildTables)
            .WithRequired(e => e.TheParentTable)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
}
```

Comment: Please also post the code for the other types (`TheBaseType`, `TheParentTable` and the context class). I tried to reproduce your error, but I got a different one, so I guess those types must make a difference.

Comment: Is the column actually an identity column in the database?

Comment: Oh wow I'm sorry guys.  I have 2 columns in the database, one is an identity and the other is not and of course the one that's not was being marked as such with the DatabaseGenerated attribute.